# How to assign keyboard keys to a GPIO command in Python Raspberry PI

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, key, curses

I am trying to make a Raspberry Pi robot using Python and I don't really know how to use curses to assign a key to a movement. I am very new to this and would like some help.

I wrote my try at the code below:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import curses 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.OUT)
try: 
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()
    stdscr.keypad(1)
    while 1:
        c = stdscr.getch()
        if c == ord('p'):
             stdscr.addstr("")
        elif c == 37:
            GPIO.output(7,False)
            GPIO.output(11,True)
            GPIO.output(13,False)
            GPIO.output(13,True)

finally: 
    curses.nocbreak(); stdscr.keypad(0)l curses.echo
    curses.endwin()
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/ROBOT_FINAL.py", line 26, in <module>
curses.nocbreak(); stdscr.keypad(0); curses.echo()
error: must call initscr() first
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it looks like an error occurs inside of your `try block`. Unfortunately, I can only assume at the moment, that the error happens during the `curses.initscr()` call.
Your `finally block` is always execute, even if an error occurred.

To diagnose this further: Can you add a `except` to your `try block` and print the error?

If you see an error like `AttributeError: 'Module' object has no attribute 'initscr'`, then you probably named your python script `curses`. Rename it and delete the 'curses.pyc' file.

Comment: Thanks for the help and also how would I add a catch to my try block? I'm pretty new at python and still learning and would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `except:`. Take a look here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html